# The upper bound of a convex combination of convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

### **Illustration**

I am reading [Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme324/saad.pdf) written by Yousef. I am a rookie of convex optimization so I am confused when the theorem involving convex optimization was just given out without any illustration as in **P132, Proof of Lemma 5.1**. ([edition 2](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Esaad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf) is given here, which is Mr copper.hat talked below)

### **Question**

$\{\lambda_i\}$ is a set of eigenvalues of some certain matrix ordered by increasing order. $$\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i=1$$
$\lambda$ is a convex combination of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$:
$$\lambda \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i\lambda_i$$
$\Psi(y)$ is a convex combination of the eigenvalues $\frac{1}{\lambda_i}$:

$$
\Psi(y) = \sum_{i=1} ^ n \beta_i\frac{1}{\lambda_i}
$$
Then Yousef just give us the upper bound directly without enough illustration for the rookies like me...
$$
\Psi(y) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_1} + \frac{1}{\lambda_n} - \frac{\lambda}{\lambda_1 \lambda_n}
$$

could anyone give me some tips about proving this, thank you

Comment: I looked for Lemma 5.1 but could not find it.

Comment: The explanation is given at the top of p.144. You need to do your own drudgework.

Comment: sry mate... I didn't check the version of the book, the latest update is given